# Magento 1.8 - Custom Block just on Homepage

Tags: magento-1.8, custom-block

I am trying to add a custom block to **just the homepage**.  All pages use the same template which is `1column.phtml`

In this file I have added a customblock above the content:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customblock') ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
```

In my layout.xml within here (I'm guessing this is the hompage?):

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">
```

I have added this:

```
<reference name="notsurethisshouldbe">
  <block type="core/template" name="customblock" template="homepage/customblock.phtml" />
</reference>
```

In `template/homepage/customblock.phtml` I have a simple page:

```
<?php
  echo "testing testing 123";
?>
```

However nothing is showing up.  What have I done wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not the correct way**. As you mentioned Just on home page you need static block

Just put below any one line code in content of your home page inside `Admin->CMS pages`

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="home_page_identifier"}} /**Add your home page identifier here***/
```

or

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="4"}} /**Add your home page id here***/
```

or

Add below code in layout update XML in CMS page

```
<block type="cms/block" name="home_block_custom" before="-">
  <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>home_page_identifier</block_id>    </action>
</block>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know your block needs to be at the top of the content you could add it to the content block, and as this is a structural block it will automatically render the template.

```
<reference name="content">
  <block type="core/template" name="customblock" template="homepage/customblock.phtml" />
</reference>
```

If it needs to be outside content then do the following:

```
<reference name="customblock">
  <block type="core/template" name="customblock" template="homepage/customblock.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Also to be consistent with Magento's naming method I recommend `custom.block` instead of `customblock`.